# Oracle function to SQL Server conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, stored-functions

I have simplified a case below which is a function in Oracle. For some reason I need to test this on a SQL Server database and I'm lost as I don't know much about SQL Server and while I know I need to demonstrate how I have tried, my conversion to SQL has been so pathetic that almost every single character is flagged as error and in red!

Could somebody please give me a hint on how to do this. It is basically to create a comma separated list using two tables. So simple and yet so frustrating! Please be gentle...it's my first SQL post :-)

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION ListOfOrdersFunction
(inputKey IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS orderNumbers VARCHAR2(3000);

BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT
    LISTAGG (selection.order_number, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY selection.customer_id)
    OVER(PARTITION BY selection.customer_id)
    INTO orderNumbers
    FROM (
      SELECT 
      customers.customerId AS customer_id
      ,orders.orderNumber AS order_number
      FROM customberTable customers
           LEFT JOIN ordersTable orders ON orders.order_key = customers.order_key
           WHERE 
                customers.customerId = inputKey
    ) selection;
  RETURN orderNumbers
END;
```

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 has a `STRING_AGG` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Squirrel: using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Please also refer to SQL Server documentation on correct syntax for creating a function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Rasul in SQL Server you can add **Linked Server** to an Oracle database server. So add a linked server and then you have the database and also it's functions in SQL Server.